# Как изменить часовой пояс при отображении даты в формате ISO 8601

Tags: php, дата, datetime

Приходят данные, например:

```
2018-09-07T12:20:21.5788091+00:00
```

, но часовой пояс не тот, как к этой дате прибавить 3 часа, чтобы получилось:

```
2018-09-07T15:20:21.5788091+00:00
```

Comment: Вы определитесь - вам нужно исправить часовой пояс или нужно прибавить три часа? Это сильно разные вещи (например, четыре года назад для Москвы нужно было прибавлять не три, а четыре часа)

Comment: @andreymal часовой пояс

Comment: Значит должно получиться '2018-09-07T15:20:21.5788091+03:00'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, в общем либо так:

`$string =  '2018-09-07T12:20:21.5788091+00:00';
  $date = new DateTime($string);
  $date->add(new DateInterval("PT3H"));
  $result = $date->format('c');`

результат '2018-09-07T15:20:21.5788091+00:00',

приплюсуется 3 часа, либо так:

```
$result = date('c', strtotime($voidDateTime));
```

результат '2018-09-07T15:20:21.5788091+03:00',

поменяется часовой пояс, в моем случае московский, те же 3 часа